# How to configure proguard to ONLY remove android logging calls

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to configure proguard to ONLY remove calls to android.util.Log from my Android app (for the release build). I specifically don't want proguard to do any obfuscation or minification of the code.

This is the configuration I've tried but it doesn't remove the `Log` calls (I assume because of the `-keep class **`)

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep class ** {
    *;
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    *;
}
```

Is what I'm asking even possible with proguard?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can remove logging calls with this option in `proguard-project.txt`:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

This option is only relevant if optimization is not disabled, like in `proguard-android.txt`. You have to specify `proguard-android-optimize.txt` instead, in `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

You can disable shrinking and obfuscation if you wish. You can also preserve the internal API of your application from optimization if you wish:

```
-keep class myapp.** { *; }
```

Disabling these steps and keeping all code of course isn't optimal from a ProGuard point of view.

Comment: Seems like the problem was the default global proguard config disables optimization.
For now I've just dropped proguard and wrapped my logging calls with a check for a debug flag.
Anyway I'll accept your answer since it solves my original question.

Comment: I noticed the web call can still show up in BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests and Request.finish following that...how would you remove that?

Comment: @Eric Could you please provide some source on that. It is not like I do not believe you, I do. But this matter is unexplained and a source of a lot of grieve.

Answer (score 13):

In build.gradle

```
buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

---

In proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn **
-target 1.7
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/allocation/variable
-keep class **
-keepclassmembers class *{*;}
-keepattributes *

#This will not remove error log
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
   public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
   #public static int e(...);
}
```

Comment: You will see error logs. Remove # before public static int e(...); and before public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int); Also make sure you run Release build. The changes were for release build.

Comment: I was wrong Sandeep. It does work.. I apologize. I missed to change proguard-android.txt - > proguard-android-optimize.txt

Comment: I want to ask one question that How can we hide complete code from APK so that no one can get code and assets by reverse engineering.