# Is there any way to turn off all VolleyLogs in release builds?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat, android-volley

I'm noticing that in my release builds there is still a bunch of Volley generated logs appearing in LogCat. Looking at `VolleyLog.java`, only verbose logs seem to be stripped out in release builds. Sadly, `VolleyLog` is hardcoded into many classes, and there doesn't seem to be any options to replace the Volley Logger other than forking Volley and making some changes to `VolleyLog`. Is there any mechanism for choosing my logging preference in Volley or am I going to need to fork it to disable logs in release?

Comment: You can use proguard for it.
See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571520/how-to-configure-proguard-to-only-remove-android-logging-calls.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Is there any better way other than this proguard solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use proguard for it.
See this question [How to configure proguard to ONLY remove android logging calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571520/how-to-configure-proguard-to-only-remove-android-logging-calls).
Also you can use this string in VolleyLog class:
public static boolean DEBUG = BuildConfig.DEBUG;

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582827/disable-volley-logs-in-android-application).

By adding:

```
VolleyLog.DEBUG = false;
```

It stops logging.