# Disable Volley logs in Android application

Tags: android, logging, android-volley

## The problem

I'm developing a SDK with using [the Volley library](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/index.html) for http(s) calls.

I'm able to hide my application logs using a customize Log class wrapper,  and I would like to disable every log level printing of `Volley`, because it might expose sensitive information sent by HTTPS.

I know you can use [proguard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/) to disable logging of application, but I also want to be able to toggle logging on and off from the server side for debugging specific scenarios.

## What have I tried

I took a look at the source, and it seems that the [DEBUG flag in the VolleyLog](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/third_party/volley/src/com/android/volley/VolleyLog.java) class only changes the log level, but keeps `ERROR` calls in the log, so it isn't a solution for me.

**Is it possible to hide all `Volley` logs ?**

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having a same issue and I can't find solution..

Comment: I'm also curious if you found a solution to this issue?  I used ProGuard, but it did not work for the Volley error logs. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554184/disable-volley-error-logs-in-aar)

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue and finally after some google search i found the solution that is worked for me

```
    VolleyLog.DEBUG = false;
```

if you set  `DEBUG` attribute to  `false` you Volley Log is disabled

Comment: Do we need to set this statement in each class or only in the starting activity?

Comment: Its better to add this line of code in Application class.

Comment: Volley still shows Log.e messages even when VolleyLog.DEBUG == false

Comment: Where I add that ?

Comment: hi , anywhere in your application ,but it is better before where you are initiate volley instance

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://github.com/google/volley/issues/125
It worked for me.

You can do this with Proguard, which is what I'd recommend as it's more efficient than flagging it off at runtime anyway. Something like:

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.android.volley.VolleyLog {
    public static void v(...);
    public static void d(...);
    public static void i(...);
    public static void w(...);
    public static void v(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with `VolleyLog.DEBUG = false;`
instead, this worked for me:

```
-assumenosideeffects class com.android.volley.VolleyLog {
    public static void v(...);
    public static void d(...);
    public static void e(...);
    public static void wtf(...);
}
```