# Are Log.i() statements removed in the published Android App?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, logging

Can I publish any Android app without deleting Log.i() statements. Is it safe?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the logs files are not removed ,
 that is why many people use **Timber library** as the Timber logs are automatically removed.
To know more about timber visit [GitHub page of Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber)

Answer (score 0):

The log statements will stay in the app and anyone can see them. You can prevent this by deleting the logs before publishing, having a check for debug mode before logging, or using something like proguard to remove them when you compile. Here's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22809567/14920442) with more info.