# Proguard Only remove Log calls

Tags: android, proguard

I have already looked at ,
[How to configure proguard to ONLY remove android logging calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571520/)  and other similar questions. I still couldn't figure out how to remove log calls, My proguard-project.txt is as follows,

```
    -dontwarn **
    -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
    -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
    -dontpreverify
    -verbose
    -optimizations     !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/allocation/variable
    -keep class **
    -keepclassmembers class *{*;}
    -keepattributes *


    -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
    }
```

I am using my signed api but still continue to generate logs.

Comment: Did you modify the `project.properties`?

Comment: the difference is the `***`

Comment: @hata I have modified  the properties.

Comment: @Budius even after I add *** it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've used that answer long time ago and worked fine for me. If you say you used exactly like that and still didn't work, I'll reopen the question and I hope someone can help you out.

Comment: I have used it exactly like that and also tried answers from similar questions, may be I am missing something which has changed recently.